# How to use Android BLE ScanFilter to filter for printers using UUID?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm a beginner in the BLE area.

Using the BLE scanner, I would like to use the ScanFilter API to filter the results using the serial port UUID: **00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb**(my target are bluetooth printers).

Currently, after starting the BLE scan, I'm not getting any results in the onScanResult method of the ScanCallback object.

Without using the filter, I'm receiving bluetooth devices correctly. I noticed that if I try to get the device UUIDs into onScanResult it returns null, while if I run the method fetchUuidsWithSdp the UUIDs are returned correctly.

Here my current code to start scanning:

```
val serviceUuidMaskString = "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF"
val parcelUuidMask = ParcelUuid.fromString(serviceUuidMaskString)
val filter = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(
    ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")), parcelUuidMask
).build()
val settings = ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED).build()
handler.postDelayed({
    bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(bleCallback)
}, 15000)
bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listOf(filter), settings, bleCallback)
```

And here the ScanCallback:

```
object : ScanCallback() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
        result?.let {
            it.device.fetchUuidsWithSdp()
            Log.i(
                TAG,
                "BLE device: ${it.device?.name.orEmpty()}\n UUIDS: ${it.device?.uuids?.joinToString()}"
            )
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BLE scanning needs runtime permissions depending on the API level. Or you can give permissions from your app's setting manually. Did you do that? Because without given permissions you won't be able to receive any results in your `ScanCallback`.

Comment: I request the runtime permissions, I found that the problem was present only in the new Android 13 version.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, I faced this problem only on devices running Android 13, when I tried to run my app on Android 12 I didn't find any issues.

The UUID of serial port (SSP_UUID) is in a different position into the array returned by

```
 BluetoothDevice.getUuids()
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247449026